# two dimensional array with random numbers doesn't change

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I'm creating an 2-dim Array with random numbers from [0,9]
and it works, but after i execute it the second time the matrix doesn't
change. Why ?

Everytime i execute my code i want a new random matrix, not the same from the old runtime. Where's the problem and how can i fix it?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

constexpr int dim_rows = 3;
constexpr int dim_cols = 5;

template <size_t dim_rows, size_t dim_cols>
void print_2d_array(int (&outputArray)[dim_rows][dim_cols]){
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim_rows; i++){
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        for(size_t j = 0; j < dim_cols; j++) {
            std::cout << outputArray[i][j] << " ";
        }std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution <int> distribution(0,9);

    int twoDimA[dim_rows][dim_cols] = {{}};

    for(int i = 1; i < dim_rows; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < dim_cols; j++) {
            twoDimA[i][j] = distribution(generator);
        }
    }

    print_2d_array(twoDimA);
}
```

Comment: `std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());`

Comment: @WhozCraig thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to seed your engine. try

`generator.seed(n);`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/default_random_engine/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `seed()` function to randomize the random number generator.  Usually just a timestamp is good enough for something like this.  You just want to make sure the seed value is different on each run.

Or a lava lamp.  You can seed with a bank of lava lamps.  Google "random number lava lamp". ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to seed your engine `generator.seed(n)` with a different number each time. By default it just uses the same seed every time, which is why you're getting the same results.

Number generators aren't truly "random", they're "[pseudorandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness)". That means that given the same seed, the sequence of numbers generated by subsequent calls will be exactly the same. However, if you provide a different seed every time (even if the seeds are close together), it will be random enough for <strike>all</strike> most purposes.

People usually choose the current clock time as a seed, or std::random_device as someone suggested, or some combination of values that change. In fields where "true" randomness is important like computer security, sometimes they even do things like take pictures of lava lamps ;)